# Swift is completely ignoring the animation for UIImageView

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview, core-animation

Animation is simply not working. Image is added to screen, but not animated. The image in the code is normally not added in the viewDidAppear function, this was just to test. Still did not help...

Below function is in a ViewController that is loaded in a PageViewController.

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(
            name: .bell,
            style: .solid,
            textColor: .white,
            size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        )

        let imageView = Init(UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)) {
            $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.image = image

        }
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        animation.duration = 7
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = -Double.pi * 2
        imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    }
```

I tried different animations but not a single animation worked. Please help....

EDIT1

```swift
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        animation.duration = 7
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: imageView.center.x - 10, y: imageView.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: imageView.center.x + 10, y: imageView.center.y))
        imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position.x")
```

EDIT2:
this does not work either:

```swift
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    override viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let keyFrame = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        let point = image!.layer.position
        keyFrame.values = [NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point.x), y: CGFloat(point.y))),
                           NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point.x - 10), y: CGFloat(point.y))),
                           NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point.x + 10), y: CGFloat(point.y))),
                           NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point.x - 10), y: CGFloat(point.y))),
                           NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point.x + 10), y: CGFloat(point.y))),
                           NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point.x - 10), y: CGFloat(point.y))),
                           NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point.x + 10), y: CGFloat(point.y))),
                           NSValue(cgPoint: point)]
        keyFrame.repeatCount = .infinity
        keyFrame.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        keyFrame.duration = 0.7
        image!.layer.position = point

        image!.layer.add(keyFrame, forKey: keyFrame.keyPath)

    }

    override func loadView() {

        var image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(
            name: .bell,
            style: .solid,
            textColor: .white,
            size: CGSize(width: 2000, height: 2000)
        )

        imageView = Init(UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)) {
            $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.image = image

        }
        self.view.addSubview(imageView!)

    }
```

Comment: You cannot add a subview and animate its layer all in one move.

Comment: As I said, I did not always had it in there. Moved it to loadView again. Still same result...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, turns out the viewDidAppear is running TOO early and thus the animation is not being set. Setting it up like this solved it. Dispatch animation after 1 sec. Even half a second was ok. Just cannot be run immediately.

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    // animation here
}
```

Pretty weird if you ask me, but whatever works.

So, no idea why I cannot run an animation directly in viewDidAppear, even when the UIView item is set up during LoadView. But this workaround helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I told you in my first comment. “You cannot add a subview and animate its layer all in one move.” The one second delay is a poor solution but it does what I said: it waits to animate until after the view is established in the visible hierarchy.

Comment: @matt as I told you, I was not adding the subview and animating in one move in the beginning. I just did it once, before posting here. Even when I add the subview in lodView(), and animate in viewDidAppear() it does not work (cf EDIT2). Only using an async invocation helps. And this was not suggested by you. If you have a better solution, please let me know. Just saying it is a poor solution does not help ;)

Comment: It is one move, because it is all part of the same opening sequence; it’s the same runloop, the same CATransaction. Your delay allows a new runloop to start.

Comment: @matt so I always need to have a delay using DispatchQueue?

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

I believe you may need to add the key here instead of nil so that this line is

```
imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "transform.rotation")
```

Also your key should probably be "transform.rotation.z" for your animation.

transform.rotation is a matrix and not a value. I believe you may still animate the entire transform.rotation but you must set that to a CATransform3D and not simple a float value.